# remove line between two container flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, containers

I have 2 containers, but in the middle of 2 containers there are unwanted lines, how can I remove them?
[image]

```
Column(
             children: [
               Container(height: 30,
                 color: Colors.white,
               ),
               Containers(
                 height: 45,
                 color : Colors.orange,
                 child: Container(
                   height: AppTheme.space3,
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                       bottomLeft: Radius.circular(AppTheme.space4),
                       bottomRight: Radius.circular(AppTheme.space4),
                     ),
                     color: Colors.white,
                   ),
                 ),
               )
]);
```

Comment: show screen please

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot what kind of line are you talking about?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25009

Comment: Try to change colors and remove the BoxDecoration for now. Try to add the changes one by one until the line reappears so you will know what causes it.

Comment: What is `Containers` in your case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can include border decoration to it.

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.white,
  border: Border.all(
    width: 0,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```

You can check [this git issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14288) which might be related.